# Can not registry a dynamic bean

Tags: spring-boot, dynamic, apache-camel, registry, javabeans

I am migrating a Project which using JBOSS fuse to Spring Boot and I use this code for registry a dynamic DataSource:

```
    PropertyPlaceholderDelegateRegistry reg = (PropertyPlaceholderDelegateRegistry) exchange.getContext().getRegistry();
        CompositeRegistry cReg = (CompositeRegistry) reg.getRegistry();
        SimpleRegistry simpleReg = new SimpleRegistry();
        simpleReg.put(
                Messaging.Names.SAM_DATABASE_CONNECTION_KEY.toString() + configuration.getCustomerNumber(),
                dataSource);
        cReg.addRegistry(simpleReg);
```

But when i migrated it to Spring boot, it does not work and has this Error: 
 There's uncaught exception has occured. Exception message:

```
org.apache.camel.spring.spi.ApplicationContextRegistry cannot be cast to org.apache.camel.impl.CompositeRegistry
```

Please help!!!

Comment: exception says it all, doesn't it? You're trying to cast a `ApplicationContextRegistry` to a `CompositeRegistry` which is impossible. Both are of type `org.apache.camel.spi.Registry` though.

Comment: but it works in Jboss Fuse so do you have any solution else??? thank you

Comment: It the datasource dynamic at runtime, or only at application-start-up-time?

Comment: at runtime Martin.